# Which data type to use for a date column with month only

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I am using MySQL. I have a date data column with month only. In other words, the data value is `Jan`, `Feb` ... There is no year and day data.

Which data type would be most appropriate? A `DATE` datatype or `VARCHAR(10)` or something else?

Comment: DATE - because later on, you'll want more information out of that field.

Comment: Can I assign, say 'Feb', without the day and year information?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need for Jan to be less than Feb, then use numbers such as 1..12 in a `TINYINT UNSIGNED` column.

If it is just for display, consider `CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET ascii`.